# Angular UI typeahead not showing dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to use the Angular UI typeahead. My problem is that the dropdown is not showing. The remote data is being called correctly and data is being returned... but the dropdown refuses to show...

```
<td colspan="5">
   <pre>Model: {{selected| json}}</pre>
   <input id="AutoCompleteDebtor" 
          type="text" 
          data-ng-model="selected" 
          data-typeahead="debtor for debtor in Debtors($viewValue)" 
          class="form-control input-sm" 
          placeholder="Enter 3 letters of Debtor Name" />
</td>
```

UPDATE: Ok - Its working well with array of string names but how do I do it with objects?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Angular Typeahead</title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.people = [
            { name: 'Alan', age: 23 },
            { name: 'Bruce', age: 24 },
            { name: 'Celine', age: 53 },
            { name: 'Dan', age: 43 },
            { name: 'Eric', age: 23 },
            { name: 'Freda', age: 47 },
            { name: 'Greg', age: 73 },
            { name: 'Hanna', age: 27 }
        ];
    });
</script>

</head>
<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
<div>
    <pre>Model: {{selected| json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="selected" data-typeahead="name for name in people | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been following the https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/typeahead example

Comment: We will need more info than this, ideally live reproduce scenario using http://plnkr.co/. What are the versions of angular-ui/bootstrap and AngularJS that you are using? There were some breaking changes in AngularJS 1.2RC1 and AngularJS 1.2RC2.

Comment: UI Bootstrap 0.6.0, Bootstrap 3.0 and Angular v1.0.8. Unfortunately, i am dealing with sensitive info so i cant copy out what I am going just yet.

Comment: no one is asking for disclosing things, just prepare an _equivalent_ example.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just couldnt do it from work. I will get to it asap.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ukAc5/1/

```
data-typeahead="n.name for n in people
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my typeahead solved from Greg's answer. Here is what I did for my typeahead (hope this helps someone):

`typeahead="i.t_UserName for i in employeeInfo | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:4"`
goes as an attribute of your html input

and in your controller (using employee resource)

```
$scope.employeeInfo = getEmployeeResourceSvc.getEmplInfo.query(function(response){
          $scope.employeeInfo= response;
});
```